# Swift: "Value of type 'Any' has no member 'map'" with array returned as type Any

Tags: swift, any

I am returning an array from a function which specifies that it's return type is `Any`. I specify the return type any because sometimes this function does not return an array and this function can return anything. Here is my code

```
import Foundation

func example() -> Any {
    return ["Example"]
}

func example2() {
    example().map {$0}
}
```

I am receiving this error

`Value of type 'Any' has no member 'map'`

How can I get rid of this error and have a function that can return anything including `Any` and `[Any]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to cast it to array

```
func example2() {
    if let array = example() as? [Any] {
       let map = array.map {$0} 
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I get `'Any' is not convertible to '[Any]'`

Comment: I don't get any issue like that

Comment: Sorry I forgot the conditional on `as`